# Are there variables for the console size in Windows?

Tags: windows, console

Does Windows has environment variables to indicate the console size? Just like Unix has LINES and COLUMNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick check with the `set` command, and no - there are no variables containing the window size, at least on Windows 7.

You can call GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo to get some information about the screen buffer including its size, but that won't be the physical size of the window due to scrolling.